# Why is req.IsAuthenticated() return false even that req.session.passport.user has everything

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Hi I have the following code. After I did `req.login`, `req._passport` has the right information there. However, after I call res.redirect("/profile"), inside my `isAuthenticated` function, `req._passport` is undefined, but `req.session.passport.user` has the right information. I looked at the req.isAuthentication method, it was looking for `req._passport`. Any reason why `req._passport` is undefined after redirect, and why there are both `req._passport` and `req.session.passport`?  Thanks!

```
app.post('/signin', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-signin', function (err, user, info) {
      ......
    req.login(user, function (err) {          
        console.log(req._passport); // Here req._passport is set.

        return res.redirect('/profile');
      });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});



app.get('/profile', isAuthenticated, profile.index);

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.passport.user); // looks good

    console.log(req._passport) // undefined
     if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("authenticated"); // Not reaching here
        return next();
     }
     console.log("not authenticated"); // reaching here
    res.redirect('/signin');
  }
```

Comment: It's stateless, you're supposed to use passport to authenticate the user for any protected route not just on sign in

Comment: thanks, does that mean that I need to do `req.Login` in the isAunthenticated method? what is the purpose of `req.isAuthenticated()` then?